# Get-Content -Raw parameter error

Tags: sql, powershell

I have a PowerShell script that would recursively loop a dir and subdir and run all SQL files inside of it and log the execution in .log files 1 for success and 1 for exceptions. The PowerShell script does what its supposed to do but in the cmd window, I see this error:

> Get-Content : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'Raw'

from this line

```bsh
$query = Get-Content -Path $_.FullName -Raw
```

This statement runs within a loop, so `FullName` changes per iteration. This is the version I use.

```
Name             : Windows PowerShell ISE Host
Version          : 5.0.10586.117
```

Sample script goes below:

```bsh
Get-ChildItem $ScriptFolder -Recurse -Exclude "*Archive*" -Filter *.sql |
  sort Directory |
  ForEach-Object { 
    $query = Get-Content -Path $_.FullName -Raw
    $result = SQLCMD -S $FullDBServer -E -I -Q $query -d $Database
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 11):

The `-Raw` parameter of `Get-Content` was introduced in PS3.

To get file contents in one string there are several methods.

- **The fastest method that works in any PS version:**
  `$text = [IO.File]::ReadAllText('c:\path\file.ext')`
- The 2 times slower method for PS3+:
  `$text = Get-Content 'c:\path\file.ext' -Raw`
- The 100 times slower PS2-compatible alternative:
  `$text = Get-Content 'c:\path\file.ext' | Out-String`
- The 30 times slower PS2-compatible alternative:
  `$text = Get-Content 'c:\path\file.ext' -ReadCount 1000 | Out-String`

Answer (score 7):

I've experienced this error in ps v 5 when the -path parameter wasn't actually a path.

Try adding `Write-Host $_.fullname` above the line throwing the error to make sure `$_.fullname` is actually what you think it is.

Comment: For me this was a good hint where to look. The actual problem was that this happens also if the **drive letter** doesn't exist (I was running this in WinPE to replace a string in a file on a USB stick which mounted as C: instead of D: while the hard drive was empty). Oddly the Get-Content won't error with "Cannot find path ... because it doesn't exist." if the whole drive doesn't exist.

Comment: Just had to solve this error, and this is the hint to bear in mind. And it doesn't occur for all invalid/nonexistent paths. In my case, I forgot to change a path (used by web admin module, e.g., "IIS:\Sites\xyz") and this specifically raised the error shown by the op.

Answer (score 3):

You're using PowerShell v2 or earlier. The parameter `-Raw` was introduced with PowerShell v3. Either upgrade PowerShell or pipe the output of `Get-Content` through `Out-String`:

```
$query = Get-Content -Path $_.FullName | Out-String
```

You should also be able to run the files directly with [`sqlcmd`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162773.aspx) (i.e. without reading their content and passing that to the command):

```
$result = SQLCMD -S $FullDBServer -E -I -i $_.FullName -d $Database
```

Comment: Am new to powershell. In your syntax, does -I and -I signify 2 diff cmds? I ve stumbled upon another issue while debugging this. 
Sqlcmd: Error: Syntax error at line 54 near command 'go'.
+$result = SQLCMD -S $FullDBServer -E -I -Q $query -d $Database
I can sense the issue is with go cmd from the script that I am running. Why does the same script work just fine in SSMS and fail in powershell? I learnt powershell turns off the quoted identifier setting by default and you have to turn it on explicitly (-I). Same way is there some switch I need to use for powershell to not error out "Go"?

Comment: I linked to the documentation explaining `sqlcmd`, its parameters, and the behavior you observed. I'm not going to read it to you.

Comment: my bad. Did not notice it. Thanks